# How to redirect user to a particular app in Market?

Tags: android

My Android app is trying to urge a user to upgrade a particular app from the Market. I can detect the old version of the app but how do I redirect user to the app page in Market directly with a button click?

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276921/how-to-handle-app-dependencies-to-3d-party

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to raise a [specially formed intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent), like this:

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Where `packageName` would be package name of your target app.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can link to it directly with a link like so:
http://market.android.com/search?q=pname:com.voxmobili.phonebook (but with a working app link that is :))

Comment: That would show search results, not app description. In case there are several apps with package name starting with 'com.voxmobili.phonebook' user would see a list of apps, not an app description.